# mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/whittle/public_html/reservations.php on line 44 First Name

Tags: sql

```
`enter code here`if (!$conn) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$sql = "SELECT name, gameID, start date of reservation, number of days game reserved FROM reservations";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


    // output data of each row LINE 43
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    }




mysqli_close($conn);
```

//ive no idea on how to fix this error, i have and index page and a reservations page , its for a games rental site please help with this

Comment: Your query has errors. Are `start date of reservation`, `number of days game reserved` fields in the database? What are these?

Comment: Your SELECT has very odd column names. Delimit them with back-ticks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use spaces in your column names (replace with *underscore* instead), it's quite bad practice. However, if it's absolutely too late to change, surround the columns with spaces in them with *ticks* like so:

```php
$sql = "SELECT name, gameID, `start date of reservation`, `number of days game reserved` FROM reservations";
```

Notice how the single quotes are angled backwards. Querying columns with spaces without these ticks will cause MySQL to give you several errors. Give that a try first, and let me know if the problem still persists.

Comment: @olliewhittle Awesome, glad I could help! Please set my answer as the accepted/correct answer if this indeed was the solution to your problem.